# Neutron star references?

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, neutron-stars

I'm looking for contemporary reviews on neutron stars. Seems like this area is pretty active, so even reviews from five or ten years ago are somewhat lacking, though certainly not worthless. Does anyone have recommendations? Newer is better.

Books are okay too, but I'd prefer one of those 70-ish page reviews you find in journals.

Comment: Recent review (quite pedagogical, 30 pages): [Insights into the physics of neutron star interiors from pulsar glitches](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2301.12769) (2022). More neutron star references: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27277/226902

Answer (score 2):

There are rather new lecture notes (1 year old) by my colleague Andreas Schnmitt focusing on the microscopic aspects of compact stars (formerly known as neutron stars): see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1001.3294).

It is more 140-ish than 70-ish, but the layout is rather generous with space, so it might be exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[The physics of neutron stars](https://doi.org/10.3367/UFNe.0180.201012c.1279) by A. Y. Potekhin (2011).

Coincidentally, this thirty-page review appears on tonights [ArXiv](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1102.5735).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest these from Living Reviews in Relativity,

[Rotating Stars in Relativity](http://emis.math.tifr.res.in/journals/LRG/Articles/lrr-2003-3/), by Nikos Stergioulas,

[Physics of Neutron Star Crust](http://emis.math.tifr.res.in/journals/LRG/Articles/lrr-2008-10/)s, by Nicolas Chamel and Pawel Haensel and

[Relativistic Fluid Dynamics: Physics for Many Different Scales](http://emis.math.tifr.res.in/journals/LRG/Articles/lrr-2007-1/), by Nils Andersson and Gregory L. Comer