# Equation of State and Neutron star

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, neutron-stars

I'm searching for equation of state books, with references to neutron star and ultra-dense matter.

Comment: Max Camenzinds book on "Compact Objects in astrophysics" covers a wide range of interesting possibilities for that.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say at what level you are studying this. Before you get stuck into the intricacies of exotic neutron star equations of state you need a good grounding in statistical mechanics and nuclear physics.

A good place to start is the first few chapters of Shapiro & Teukolsky; "White Dwarfs, Neutron Stars and Black Holes" (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Black-Holes-White-Dwarfs-Neutron/dp/0471873160), paying close attention to the sections on the cold equation of state below and above the neutron drip. Get to grips with the ideas behind (i) ideal fermion degeneracy pressure; (ii) the Harrison Wheeler equation of state; (iii) the ideal n,p,e,$\mu$ gas. This is a very authoritative text; I find it not too hard to digest - at least the parts I mention above. However, things have moved on quite a bit since it was published, particularly on the nucleon interactions in dense, many-body systems; the appearance of hyperons; pion/kaon condensation and quark matter. For these I have used a variety of sources:

I found the thesis of Martin Urbanec (2010) an excellent read (it can still be found here).

https://pdfcoffee.com/neutron-star-pdf-free.html

It covers Skyrme models, relativistic mean field models, rotating neutrons stars, strange stars, the MIT bag model, and importantly, a comparison of models with observations.

There are several reviews of the topic by John Lattimer; he is very strong on what observations can constrain. A recent, quite substantial one is [Lattimer (2013)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3510v1.pdf).

An older, but highly cited overview is by [Lattimer & Prakash (2001)](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/550/1/426/fulltext/)

[Gulminelli (2013)](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/550/1/426/fulltext/) provides a reasonable review of progress in the EOS over the last 20 years.

I found this review by [Heiselberg & Hjorth-Jensen (2000)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000PhR...328..237H) good for a description of the EOS of asymmetric nuclear matter and the possible phase changes at high densities.

[Weber et al. (2008)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.2708v2.pdf) provide a lots of discussion about the exotica - meson condensation, hyperons, quark deconfinement and especially strange matter.

You could also look at some of the literature cited in answers to this related question: [Introduction to neutron star physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/introduction-to-neutron-star-physics?rq=1)

Comment: Hi @RobJeffries, the link to Martin Urbanec's thesis is dead now. Can you fix it?

Comment: @Urb finally found a link to a copy.