# Observational evidence for superfluidity in neutron stars

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, neutron-stars, superfluidity

What is the earliest evidence for the existence of superfluidity in neutron stars?

I'm about to present the subject in a seminar and I'm under the impression that at the moment there is no conclusive evidence the superfluidity actually exists in neutron stars (although it is widely believed to be so?).

I've found [this review by Chamel (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07288), but it doesn't seem to be very conclusive.

Comment: I think the best evidence is the rapid cooling of the neutron star remnant in Cas A. But as that is discussed in your Chamel reference, I don't think I can add anything.

Comment: The evidence comes from cooling and [pulsar glitches](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/781603/226902). The cooling observations are very delicate and have been recently revised, finding no evidence for the "rapid cooling" that would imply the presence of superfluidity. On the other hand, glitches are a quite robust indicator that there is superfluidity in "cold" neutron stars https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/781603/226902 For a recent review, see: [Insights into the physics of neutron star interiors from pulsar glitches (2022)](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2301.12769).